# OpenAM JEE Policy Agents 3.5 & 5.x

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, openam

Why ForgRock stop supporting OpenAM JEE Policy Agents(3.5)
https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam-jee-policy-agents/3.5/jee-users-guide/

and the newer versions from Java Agents 5.x only support AM 5.5 and later. and Not Support openAM
https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam-jee-policy-agents/5/java-agents-rnotes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why ForgRock stop supporting OpenAM JEE Policy Agents(3.5)

No company can provide support for each and every version for ever.

> and the newer versions from Java Agents 5.x only support AM 5.5 and
>   later. and Not Support openAM

ForgeRock Access Manager has been evolving over time and got rid of some of the quite old legacy stuff of its predecessors. Agents 5 have moved to using REST APIs instead of the old XMl/HTTP protocol, but those REST APIs are not offered by OpenAM.

Comment: If i used openAM with JEE Policy Agents(3.5) is this will be a bad decision because i will be stucked with this  version from openam and JEE agent?
Also is openAM product differ from AM product?
   1.which one i can use it in production environment ?
   2. which one is free and opensource?

Comment: thanks @Bernhard Thalmayr, could you please check my previous comment

Comment: If I used openAM with JEE Policy Agents(3.5) is this will be a bad decision because I will be stuck with this version from openAM and JEE agent? 

Also is openAM product differ from AM product? 1.which one I can use it in a production environment? 2. which one is free and opensource?

Comment: Forgerock Access Management is neither free of charge nor open source.